# Values of a vector without variable names

Tags: r, simplify

In R you can do this to retrieve the values of the elements of an numeric vector where `time > 20`

```
time <- c(17, 16, 20, 24, 22, 15, 21, 15, 17, 22)
time[time>20]
```

But how could I do this without first assigning the vector?
Is there something like:

```
c(17, 16, 20, 24, 22, 15, 21, 15, 17, 22)[%>20]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a pipe operator (`|>`) from `base R`

```
c(17, 16, 20, 24, 22, 15, 21, 15, 17, 22) |> 
     {\(x) subset(x, x > 20)}()
```

-output

```
[1] 24 22 21 22
```

---

Or with `dplyr/magrittr` `%>%`

```
c(17, 16, 20, 24, 22, 15, 21, 15, 17, 22) %>% 
  .[. > 20]
[1] 24 22 21 22
```